# Update event in recurrence event

Tags: ios, eventkit

i am trying to update and with recurrence rule.

in my app i create repeating event that repeat every day. if i am trying to change one of the events (not the root) all of the events are deleted!

i try to use

```
[self.eventStore saveEvent:event span:[self getEKSpan:span] commit:YES error:&err];
```

the getEKSpan:span is return EKSpanThisEvent!

after this line all the rest of the instance of this event ( from this one ) will delete!

if someone know what is the reason it will be very helpful.

FYI: if i will try to edit FutureEvents every thing will be ok ... the rest of the event will be update and nothing will be delete...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found the problem :)

before

```
[self.eventStore saveEvent:event span:[self getEKSpan:span] commit:YES error:&err];
```

i change the event.recurrenceRules even if i didn't change anything... 
we need to be carful with this change !

Enjoy